# my build.gradle (project-level) looks different android studio dolphin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gradle

I created a new project and this is what my build.gradle file contains:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.3.1' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

there is no build scripts and know I don't know where to add dependencies.
is it a new thing or what?

Comment: I haven't done android dev in a long time, but this looks pretty normal to me. Just add a `dependencies { }` block to add your dependencies

Comment: no i thing there should be some thing like build scripts , repositories,...

Comment: Well it all depends on how the general build is defined. Check the `settings.gradle(.kts)` file(s) and how they include different builds from different folders, and check the potential other `build.gradle(.kts)` files (add them to the question if you find some). `buildScript` blocks are only useful to customize the behaviour of your build file itself, but it's completely optional, and could be declared elsewhere, or entirely superseded by the `plugins{}` block you have. `repositories { }` might be declared in other places.

Comment: Note that properly structured Gradle builds shouldn't have complicated project build scripts. Lots can be done via plugins (maybe convention plugins, or compiled plugins), so the different subprojects are simple.

Answer (score 2):

The `plugins` block replaced the `apply plugin` block.

It uses the syntax:

```
plugins {
    id «plugin id» version «plugin version» [apply «false»]
}
```

The `apply` false after the plugin declaration means that it's just added to the classpath without also applying it to the project. This is useful if you want to declare all plugins and their versions in the root project.

In your case:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.3.1' apply false
}
```

replaces:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    //...
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:x.x.x'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

In the `settings.gradle` you can find the repositories used to find the plugins:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

You can add other repos and also other plugins in same blocks.

Then in your `app/build.gradle` file you can find:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}
```

In the same file you can add other dependencies adding the `dependencies` block:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    //
}
```

and the `repositories` block

```
   repositories {
        google()
    }
```

In the `settings.gradle` you can find also the repositories used by the module dependencies:

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```